# Use cookie in SQL where statement

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2010

In Visual Studio using c#  Does anyone know how to use a cookie from one page in a sql where statement on another page. I am trying to pull information from a database in grid form depending on certain values in certain columns. People search cinema listing from the page that stores the cookie. As in select from movies where `[FilmName] = "CookieValue"`.
Thanks 
SQL 
" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT [FilmName], [Date], [Time], [Bookings] FROM [CinemaListings]">
    
Cookie I want to use in where clause form another page that directs to page with code shown above
protected void btnsubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Cookies["SelectedConty"].Value = CountyDrop.SelectedItem.Text;
        Response.Cookies["SelectedFilm"].Value = FilmDrop.SelectedItem.Text;
        Response.Cookies["SelectedCinema"].Value = CinemaDrop.SelectedItem.Text;
        //Response.Write(Response.Cookies["SelectedConty"].Value);
        Response.Redirect("CinemaListings2.aspx");
    }

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly access the cookie from the database however you could simply read the value from your web server page (assuming you have one) and pass it along.  If you have no server web page/handler/controller etc.. then you're out of luck.